# Is there any donors list?

Tags: canonical, commercial

I wonder if there is any list for companies that donate money to Ubuntu.

These companies are not necessarily from IT and since they are using ubuntu in their daily bases intensively, they would like to have some donation. But it is important to know how these donation will be spent and if their donations will be shown to public !!

So, the question is if there is any list of these companies ? like the one in [R project](http://www.r-project.org/foundation/memberlist.html#bene)

Answer (score 4):

There are probably thousands of companies and organizations that donate time, money, and code to Ubuntu/Debian and various software. Of course the big one is Canonical.

Comment: I am mainly wonder about those who donate with money ! and if there is such a link, is it publicly available which companies?

Comment: I am not aware of any such list..

Comment: Can Canonical make such a list ?! I believe they are many companies who are not a part of IT industry but would like to participate in open source community.